# Crop screenshot to element in PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I know it's possible to arbitrarily crop a screenshot in PhantomJS, using `page.clipRect()`:

```
            page.clipRect = { 
                top: element_top, 
                left: element_left, 
                width: element_width, 
                height: element_height 
            };
```

So, I am trying to grab the positioning and width/height of a specific element using jQuery. However, my code below (based on the last section of the PhantomJS [rasterize.js example](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart)) isn't working; it just keeps the default values.

I'm thinking I must have done something wrong with respect to variable scope. How can I get this to work?

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {

        var element_top = 0;
        var element_left = 0;           
        var element_width = 200;
        var element_height = 200;

        page.evaluate(function() { 
                var $element = $('h1');
                var offset = $element.offset();
                element_top = offset.top;
                element_left = offset.left;
                element_width = $element.width();
                element_height = $element.height();     
        });

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.clipRect = { 
                top: element_top, 
                left: element_left, 
                width: element_width, 
                height: element_height 
            };

            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you run inside `page.evaluate` is not available from the outside world, the execution is sandboxed and confined with the page context. In order to have it available, make it as a return value and then you can access it.

Take a look at PhantomJS included `pizza.js` where the list of the pizzeria is returned back the caller.

Comment: is `pizza.js` still available I cannot find it on Github.