# Capture screenshot of specific element using NodeJS and Browserstack

Tags: node.js, selenium, browserstack

Does anyone know if there's a way to use NodeJs to drive Browserstack and capture a screenshot of a specific element on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Screenshot the entire page:
[Phantomjs - take screenshot of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189745/phantomjs-take-screenshot-of-a-web-page)

Screenshot cropped to the dimensions of a specific element:
[Crop screenshot to element in PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959139/crop-screenshot-to-element-in-phantomjs)

More PhantomJS examples: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples

Comment: Thanks!  However, the reason I wanted to do it with Browserstack or Selenium is to get the true rendering of the page with differen browsers / rendering engines...

Comment: Browserstack has an [example](http://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#enhancements-screenshots) of taking a full page screenshot. To capture a specific element you'd need to find the element, get it's position + dimensions and then crop the png screenshot. There are a few methods for cropping - you can "paste" the base64 png onto a canvas - see [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/resize.js). You can use imagemagick or gmagick - see [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/).

Comment: Browserstack also has a ["Screenshots API"](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api). Does not appear to support cropping - you'd have to do that in a separate process. You cant get the element position/dimensions either. Does not sound like a suitable solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

The below given links give a sample to capture screenshot of an element using php. You can use it as a reference to write code in Node. If you face any problem, please feel free to ask.

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Taking-Full-Screenshot-and-of-an-Element

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/firstandthird/stackshots

Comment: this doesn't allow screenshots of specific elements, just full pages